# How can I make N2CMS show edit page in admin interface by default?

Tags: n2cms, n2

When I am in the N2 management / admin interface, if I click on a node in the tree, by default it shows the output of that page. I can show the edit screen for that node by right clicking the node and clicking 'Edit'. Can I get it to show the edit screen for that node by just clicking the node? Is there some setting I can change in web.config?

Comment: Having looked through the N2 code, it looks like there's no option for this. However, if you're not using the N2 page routing for your site (as we are not) then you can override TemplateUrl on your ContentItems like so:

`public override string TemplateUrl
{
    get { return String.Format("/N2/Content/Edit.aspx?selected={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(AncestralTrail)); }
}`

Comment: You could probably also expand this code to check if user is authenticated, then return return either edit link or standard TemplateUrl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the comment that I left on the question above doesn't really answer the question (it works only for the root node). However, pretty much everything in N2 is pluggable, so you can use the dependency injection framework to replace the code that generates URLs in the edit interface with your own code as follows:

```
using N2.Configuration;
using N2.Edit;
using N2.Engine;
using N2.Web;

namespace MyWebsite
{
    [Service(typeof(IEditUrlManager), Replaces = typeof(EditUrlManager))]
    public class MyEditUrlManager : EditUrlManager
    {
        public MyEditUrlManager(IUrlParser parser, EditSection config)
            : base(parser, config)
        {

        }

        public override string GetPreviewUrl(N2.ContentItem selectedItem)
        {
            return GetEditExistingItemUrl(selectedItem);
        }
    }
}
```